# Steepest ascent and descent of a function

Tags: calculus

For the function

$z = x^2 + y^2/4$ ,

find the direction of its steepest descent,steepest ascent, and no change at the point

$( \sqrt2/2, \sqrt2 )$
on the level curve `z = 1`.

I think I'm supposed to compute the directional derivative. I have the point required to do this, but not a vector (the question's answer should be a vector). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of steepest ascent is the gradient.  The direction of steepest descent is the negative of the gradient.  If you traveled along the ellipse $x^2 + y^2 / 4$ then there would be no change; this would be the tangent vector to the ellipse with z remaining constant at 1.

Comment: My function represents an ellipse, though. Don't you mean traveling along $x^2+y^2/4 $ would be no change?

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong.  I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: So then I'm not supposed to compute the directional derivative to find the direction of its steepest descent. I'm to find the gradient, correct?

Comment: The way I read the question, I would say that's correct.  I'm not sure why the part "... on the level curve $z=1$" is written.  I suspect that it's supposed to be a hint that ends up just being confusing.